# Android: problems with saving picture to sd card after activity result

Tags: android, image, android-camera, android-sdcard, image-size

I have two problems in my program:
1.After taking a picture, this is what I have for onActivityResult():

```
        pictureTaken = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view);
        im.setImageBitmap(pictureTaken);
```

This displays only a thumbnail (bad quality when displayed), and when I save it to the SD card, it is also a small image. What I need is to save/display it in it's full resolution/quality. What do I change to achieve this?

1. Retrieving and displaying the image selected by the user works:

   ```
   selectedImage = data.getData();
   ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view);
   im.setImageURI(selectedImage);
   ```

But when saving the image the user picked, it crashes here (found by debugger):

```
...
File externalStorageFile = new File(dir, finalName);
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//Error
resourceImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
byte b[] = bytes.toByteArray();
try {
...
```

Also, is bitmap the only way you can save images in Android?

Comment: what does the stack trace say?  Please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Links for Sample. If the Selected images from Gallery shows Bitmap out of range exception you need to Decode image.

[Scale Image to screen Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410364/how-to-scale-bitmap-to-screen-size/6410472#6410472)....

[Picking Image from gallery and Decode it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123557/how-to-upload-images-from-sd-card-by-picking-over-them-in-android/6124781#6124781).......

Comment: I'm getting a nullPointerException... found where too! It's when trying to decode

Comment: Bitmap bImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImage.getPath());

Comment: Yea! Thanks for the second link, it helped me with the decoding error. As for the 1st problem, I still need to read the link more thoroughly and see what I can find. Also, since my app is honeycomb optimized, what should I set the bitmap too (bImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bImage, 500, 500, true);)? 500 seems ok, but if they want to transfer the photo to their computer, shouldn't I use the same/similar size as the "gallery" app does?

Comment: Thank YOU for helping at least get one step closer to finish my app!

Answer (score 0):

For saving the image in **sdcard** use the below code

```
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, imagename);
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new  FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

Comment: This part I have, the saving works fine, it just that the 5mp camera is returning a 80X80 photo with my code. Am I not "getting data" the right way?