# How to draw a bitmap from sdcard to custom ondraw method

Tags: android, image, canvas, sd-card

I have a image on sdcard can anyone tell me how to draw the image from sdcard onto the custom ondraw method

Comment: your question is not that clear. see if this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123557/how-to-upload-images-from-sd-card-by-picking-over-them-in-android?rq=1 helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer actually to draw a image from sdcard we have to intialize the image again in the function below

```
      public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
       {

            ball=BitmapFactory.createScaledBitmap(src,width,height,true);
            bgr=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/1364275090569.jpg");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is my code and in this i am able to draw and customly move the image over background through the images placed in the resource folder but when i load a image instead from the sdcard and then implement it the application gives error

```
public class Preview extends Activity{

 BallBounces ball;
 public static int wd;
 public static int ht;
public static  String txt;
public static String path;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    Intent i=getIntent();

    ball = new BallBounces(this);
    setContentView(ball);

     txt=i.getStringExtra("bpath");
     path=i.getStringExtra("path");

    wd= getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    ht=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();



}
```

}
class BallBounces extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
public float mPosX=0;
public float mPosY=0;
public float mLastTouchX;
public float mLastTouchY;

//For Fetching image
private Bitmap bmp;
private Drawable image;
private byte[] byteArray;
private ByteArrayBuffer baf = null;
int wid =Preview.wd, hght = Preview.ht;
//For Rotation
int direction = 0;
int degree = 0;
String twxt=Preview.txt;
String pth=Preview.path;
float wdth,hgt;
private float newX ;
public float newY ;
private float rotateX;
private float rotateY;
private float imgX;
private float imgY;
 GameThread thread;
public int screenW; //Device's screen width.
public int screenH; //Devices's screen height.
public int ballX; //Ball x position.
public  int ballY; //Ball y position.
int initialY ;
float dY; //Ball vertical speed.
int ballW;
int ballH;
int bgrW;
int bgrH;
int angle;
int bgrScroll;
int dBgrY; //Background scroll speed.
float acc;
Bitmap ball, bgr, bgrReverse;
boolean reverseBackroundFirst;
boolean ballFingerMove;
Bitmap d;
//Measure frames per second.
long now;
int framesCount=0;
int framesCountAvg=0;
long framesTimer=0;
Paint fpsPaint=new Paint();

//Frame speed
long timeNow;
long timePrev = 0;
long timePrevFrame = 0;
long timeDelta;




public BallBounces(Context context) {
    super(context);



    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bubble);//load image
   bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.grd); //Load a background.

    bgrW = bgr.getWidth();
    bgrH = bgr.getHeight();

    ballW = ball.getWidth();
    ballH = ball.getHeight();



    image =new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources() , ball);

    imgX=image.getIntrinsicWidth();
    imgY=image.getIntrinsicHeight();

    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener()); 
    //Set thread
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    //This event-method provides the real dimensions of this custom view.
    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;
    System.out.println(w+"  X  "+h);
   bgr = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bgr, w, h, true); //Scale background to fit the screen.
    bgrW = bgr.getWidth();
   bgrH = bgr.getHeight();


}

//***************************************
//*************  TOUCH  *****************
//***************************************
@Override
public synchronized boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

     mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getActionMasked();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {


            System.out.println("DOWN");
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            System.out.println("DOWN-POSITION--"+x+"  X  "+y);
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0); 
        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            System.out.println("MOVE");
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            System.out.println("Moving points" +x+" X "+y);

            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;

                final float dy=y-mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;
                newX=ev.getRawX();
                newY=ev.getRawY();

                System.out.println("Image Config" +newX+"  X  "+newY);
                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;



        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            System.out.println("UP");
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;


        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            System.out.println("CANCEL");
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            System.out.println("ACTN_POINTER_UP");
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
            >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;

        }

        return true;
}

public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){



    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(twxt,0,twxt.length(),bounds);
    float height = bounds.height();
    float width = bounds.width();
    wdth=width/2;
    hgt=height/2;

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);  
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    paint.setTextSize(15); 
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    int xPos =(int) ((bm.getWidth()/2)-wdth);

    int yPos = (int) ((bm.getHeight()/2)-hgt) ;

    canvas.drawText(text, xPos-(wdth/8),yPos+hgt, paint);
    return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
}



@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Rect fromRect1 = new Rect(0, 0, bgrW - bgrScroll, bgrH);
    Rect toRect1 = new Rect(bgrScroll, 0, bgrW, bgrH);

    Rect fromRect2 = new Rect(bgrW - bgrScroll, 0, bgrW, bgrH);
    Rect toRect2 = new Rect(0, 0, bgrScroll, bgrH);

    if (!reverseBackroundFirst) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, fromRect1, toRect1, null);

    }
    else{
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, fromRect2, toRect2, null);

    }


   if(mPosX<0)
    {
        mPosX=0;
    }
    if(mPosX>screenW-ballW)
    {
        mPosX=screenW-ballW;
    }
    if(mPosY>screenH-ballH)
    {
        mPosY=screenH-ballH;
    }

    if(mPosY<0)
    {
        mPosY=0;
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(ball, mPosX, mPosY, null); 
     canvas.drawText(mPosX+ "  X  "+mPosY, 40, 70, fpsPaint);
     canvas.drawText(ballW+ "  X  "+ballH, 40, 100, fpsPaint); 

     canvas.drawText(screenW+ "  X  "+screenH, 40, 150, fpsPaint);
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}



public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    thread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}


class GameThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private BallBounces gameView;
    private boolean run = false;

    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, BallBounces gameView) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gameView = gameView;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        this.run = run;
    }

    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return surfaceHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (run) {
            c = null;

            //limit frame rate to max 60fps
            timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
            timeDelta = timeNow - timePrevFrame;
            if ( timeDelta < 16) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(16 - timeDelta);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
            timePrevFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();

            try {
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                   //call methods to draw and process next fame
                    gameView.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

}